# How is the :nth-child pseudo-class-selector working here?

Tags: html, css

```css
div:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(odd):nth-child(-n+9) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
<div>11</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>13</div>
<div>14</div>
<div>15</div>
```

I don't understand why the certain `div`s that're selected to be red are selected. Can we, step-by-step, explain? I understand pretty well how one `nth-child` works - but not when they are in combination with each other.

For instance, why isn't the 2nd div selected from (0 + 2)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step by step:

1. n+2 you select the second and every element after the second
2. odd you select the odd ones from the previously selected
3. -n+9 you select the ninth and every element before that from the previously selected

conclusion:
You have selected every odd element that is between the second and ninth including them as well. That means you haven't selected the second one because 2 is not an odd number.

Answer (score 0):

The `nth-child(odd)` selector only selects elements that are odd, meaning that 2 isn't selected because it is even.

The first one isn't picked because `2` was added to `n`.

This is a bit confusing, though, as you have quite a lot of selectors.

Please consider that `nth-child` counts up from 1, not 0.

Comment: So how do all the `nth-child` selectors work when they are in combination with each other? A tag has to satisfy all conditions to be selected?

Comment: Yes, a tag always has to satisfy all conditions. Say for example, `.example1.example2`

Answer (score 0):

Apply different properties to understand the pattern

```css
div:nth-child(n+2) {
  font-size:30px
}

div:nth-child(odd) {
  border:1px solid #000;
}

div:nth-child(-n+9) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
<div>11</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>13</div>
<div>14</div>
<div>15</div>
```

The elements having all the properties are your selection